# Point git tag to a specific commit id

Tags: git, git-tag

How can I point git tag to a specific commit id?

For Example : I have following commits

#git log
    6470098 change1
    b72099b change2
    1514994 change3
    068bf4c change4

I need to tag `1514994`. How will I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git tag`. Let’s suppose you like to create a tag named `v1.0` at commit `068bf4c`.

```
git tag V1.0 068bf4c
```